# mi package r pool function giving error

Tags: r

I've been having problems running a simple lm on an mi dataset with the new mi package.

I tried the example given in the mi manual (to make sure it wasn't a silly mistake) and still no luck
This is from the manual:

```
if(!exists("imputations", env = .GlobalEnv)) {
    imputations <- mi:::imputations # cached from example("mi-package")
}
```

I checked to make sure imputations loaded ok, it did
    names(imputations)

but when I try this:

```
analysis <- 06pool(ppvtr.36 ~ first + b.marr + income + momage + momed + momrace,
        data = imputations)
```

I get:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'INTERP' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Is this a package bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 06 in front of pool, i.e. instead of:

```
analysis <- 06pool(ppvtr.36 ~ first + b.marr + income + momage + momed + momrace,
    data = imputations)
```

Write:

```
analysis <- pool(ppvtr.36 ~ first + b.marr + income + momage + momed + momrace,
    data = imputations)
```

and it should work.